# How to make matplotlib show dates in x-axis without plotting spaces in weekends

Tags: python, date, matplotlib

I've been using [this](http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/date_index_formatter.html) example: 
and I am trying to use the code shown below to make grid locate the first date (first date in csv file, so it might be e.g. 3. July instead of 1. July).

```
months = matplotlib.dates.MonthLocator()
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(months)
```

However when I write the code above all dates disappear, and the grid show no lines marking the x-axis (see code 2 below):

[image]

How can I make `set_major_locator()` to locate the first day in month (first available from csv file)? 
In the picture below I've made the grid locate first day in month by using

```
ax.plot(r.date, r.adj_close, 'o-')
months = matplotlib.dates.MonthLocator()
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(months)
```

[image]

The problem here is that empty days make spaces, and this makes problems when I'm trying to plot lines on the graph.

edit:
Code 1 (puts grid in right place, but makes trouble when I try to plot lines as it makes spaces in weekends etc):

```
def plot1(price, date):
    # first we'll do it the default way, with gaps on weekends
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.plot(date, price, 'o-',c='black', markersize=2.7, linewidth=0.9)
    ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%m-%Y-%d'))
    days_locator = mdates.DayLocator(bymonthday=[1,])
    ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(days_locator)
    ax.set_title("Default")
    fig.autofmt_xdate()
    ax.grid()
    plt.show()
```

Code 2 (set_major_locator() doesn't work):

```
def plot2(price, date):
    # next we'll write a custom formatter
    N = len(price)
    ind = np.arange(N)  # the evenly spaced plot indices
    def format_date(x, pos=None):
        thisind = np.clip(int(x + 0.5), 0, N - 1)
        return date[thisind].strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.plot(ind, price, 'o-',c='black', markersize=2.7, linewidth=0.9)
    ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mticker.FuncFormatter(format_date))
    ax.set_title("Custom tick formatter")
    days_locator = mdates.DayLocator(bymonthday=[1,])
    ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(days_locator)
    fig.autofmt_xdate()
    ax.grid()
    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

To locate the first day of months, you should use:

```
days_locator = mdates.DayLocator(bymonthday=[1,])
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(days_locator)
```

Comment: It doesn't work for plot2 (I added the scripts for the two plots in the bottom of the first post)

Comment: There are various problems in the code, I suggest to see the example at: https://matplotlib.org/examples/api/date_demo.html